# Loop over filenames, rename them via a condition

Tags: bash, for-loop, filenames

How do I loop over separate filenames and rename them?
The "task/condition" is:
Cut the first 5 letters and the last 4 letters?

e.g. I have these files:

```
1212erertugg.jpg
14rtzuzuiopo.jpg
tz7878nhmnop.jpg
etc...
```

The result should look like this:

```
rertugg
uzuiopo
8nhmnop
```

Comment: What did you try and how did it fail?

Comment: Which part are you stuck on? Looping over files, extracting a substring, or renaming them?

Comment: I stuck on: "extracting a substring"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use parameter expansion to extract the substrings:

```
#!/bin/bash
for file in 1212erertugg.jpg 14rtzuzuiopo.jpg tz7878nhmnop.jpg ; do
    substr=${file:5}
    substr=${substr:0:-4}
    mv "$file" "$substr"
done
```

You might need to check whether you're not overwriting an already existing file, either an original one or created by the script itself in one of the previous steps.

Comment: @EdMorton: Fixed (partially) :-)